# Is it possible to implement PhantomJS/CasperJS with HTML page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

**Things I did**

Implemented in ASP.NET with C#.

Currently, I'm getting data from another website by using selenium webdriver + PahntomJS, and It's working fine as expected with headless browser experience.

**Problem :** I disabled image loading for phantomJS though this full process is taking around 60 seconds of time.

**Things I want to implement If it's possible**

My current implemention is very time consuming process in c#.

I want the whole program to loop and run continually but When I was going through Phantom documentation 
I got the impression it's a command line tool.

So is it possible to implement directly in html page and perform the same loop of process in JS that I'm doing with webdriver in C#.

Please share any document or code if you have solution.

Comment: Do you mean in the client browser? PhantomJS scripts are written in javascript or coffeescript and are then run through the command line tool.

Comment: Yes, Is it possible to get data in webpage without manually running command in command line tool of phantomjs?
I am beginner at this level, so don't know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: In what way is it "just" a command line tool?